# Remove lastname field from checkout page in magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Is there a way to remove lastname field from checkout page ?
i follow this tutotrial http://www.douglasradburn.co.uk/how-to-make-last-name-optional-in-magento-1-9/#comment-28589 , but in the end it still show an error: lastname must to be greater than one 
Thanks

Comment: Did you try updating db as in this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13878/how-to-make-last-name-optional-in-magento-1-8

Comment: I did it but the error is still there